# Best/quickest way to learn Java for a seasoned .NET/C# and C++ developer

Tags: c#, java, .net

What is the quickest/easiest way to learn Java for a seasoned .NET/C# (more than 7 years) and C++ (5years) developer.

When I say to learn Java - I mean being able to write applications in a "Java way" using base classes library + where needed using a popular Java libraries (it is great that so many of them are open source).

I know that Java development comes in a lot of flavors - enterprise applicatons (Java EE), mobile devices (Java ME), objects hosted in application servers (to my knowledge Java has a buch of these) - however at the moment I am interested in a general Java development - may be with a some emphasis on a integration projects/enterprise development.

So basically - I am a strong, passionate about technology, proud to be a senior C#/C++ developer with a dozen years of experience who wants to dedicate a month-worth (may be more) of evenings to learn to effectively program in Java environment.

Having said that I don't mean I am switching from .NET/C++ to Java - but I would probably have to spend 30%-50% of my development time developing/supporting/whateverstageintheSDLC in Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I suggest starting with [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/). I don't think there is any quicker or more comprehensive way of gaining an understanding of the language for a seasoned programmer.
2. Followed by [Java Collections Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).
3. Followed by [`java.lang.*`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) and [`java.util.*`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) classes, interfaces and packages.

This will give a good basis for learning and understanding any other branch of Java as it becomes necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I started reading lang ref - reads good so far. Then I will follow with other suggestion and will read Thinking in Java and Effective Java books. Feels like a good start of an interting journey!

Comment: The collections tutorial is linked to the language spec page, this seems to be the right one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html

Answer (score 7):

I would take a completely different approach to reading books upfront. Simply download an IDE and get coding. The netbeans tutorials tend to get you up and running with a variety to technologies very quickly.

If you can code C# then you should have no problem getting something up and running.

Once you have some code up and running that is when you would then dig out the likes of effective Java.

Karl

Answer (score 5):

[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) should be in every Java developer's bookshelf. It focuses not so much on performance as one might think from the title, but rather on how to program Java idiomatically, which becomes subtly different from following the idioms of C#.

Comment: I've read neither but FWIW, Effective Java has a better overall average rating on Amazon (5 stars) than the book in @Bevan's answer, Thinking in Java (4 stars).

Comment: Note that the word "effective" does not mean "efficient", but rather "being able to produce the desired effect".

Comment: This is a very good Java book, but it is not a beginner's book. I agree that every Java developer should read this book, but a beginner will need another book (or online tutorial, or something) first, to learn the basics.

Comment: Well, yes, maybe if you're a *beginner*, but I'd hardly say you're a beginner if you've been programming C# for a decade. While there are important differences, it's not like you're jumping from QBASIC to Haskell.

Comment: I used the first edition of this book to move from C++ to Java about 7 or 8 years ago.  The structure of Java is very easy, and the compiler will tell you if its wrong.  The Standard Library is very easy with online javadoc.  Programming is easy if you have a few years experience.  The hard part is programming in a clean style that works with the language (not against it), this book covers exactly that.  This book and practice are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one of the best ways would be to get a copy of Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ4).

Much more than simply covering the syntax of the language, this book goes into the background - as the title says, "How to **think** in Java" so you can write pure Java code, not C# (or C++) code using Java Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I m only speaking for java web app development: i think its going to be quite similar to how you might've done it in C# using ASP.NET, except you don't get the visual drag and drop GUI creation using visual studio. The basic concepts are pretty much the same.

As for libraries, there are a million and one in java, and only time will help with those. But it'll help knowing the common ones, such as [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/), [google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), [spring](http://www.springsource.org/documentation), [hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/5.html). It might help you get started if you start with something like [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart), which is a full java RAD web app framework that munges together all the above common frameworks.

On the build tools side, there are [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) and [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as the major players. I prefer ant over maven personally.

Answer (score 0):

Ordered list:

1. [Thinking in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486);
2. [Core Java, Volume II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354799);
3. [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html);